# Magento 2.X: Sort Product Collection by Category Product Position

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-2.0

I would like to sort the list of my Product Collection by its category product position. Right now I have this function

```
public function getProducts($category, $productFactory, $store)
{    
    $collection = $productFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');    
    $anchorFlag = $category->getIsAnchor(); // Remove this if we want to include the child products within the parent category    
    $collection->setStore($store);
    $collection->addUrlRewrite($category->getId());
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);         
    $collection->setOrder('position','ASC');

    return $collection;
}
```

As you can see right now. The list of products are Ordered by its position in `Catalog->Product` (CMS) so meaning it's ordered by its ID? or something right?. What I want is to retrieve the product by its position in a `Catalog->Categories->Products`. The idea is I have 5 products and 3 of this are assigned under a certain category. So what I want to do is order them based on their position in the Categories->Product list and NOT under PRODUCT Position.

What I was thinking to solve this is to Join the Product Collection with the Category Collection using the category ID and with that, I can sort it by product position. If I were to translate it into a SQL Query I want something like this

````
SELECT products.* 
FROM products 
INNER JOIN category ON (products.category_id = category.id) 
WHERE category.id = {category_id} 
ORDER BY category.products.position;```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by changing your `getProducts()` function to

```
public function getProducts($category, $productFactory, $store)
{    
    $collection = $productFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');    
    $anchorFlag = $category->getIsAnchor();   
    $collection->setStore($store);
    $collection->addUrlRewrite($category->getId());
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);         
    $collection->setOrder('cat_index_position','ASC');
    return $collection;
}
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: Sumit I know what does cat_index_position do?

Comment: **cat_index_position** is for the position of the products defined in the category products section

Comment: Wow this is actually the thing that I need. Will test this out later after an hour. Will definitely accept this answer once I finish trying this out. Great stuff thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 7):

The **cat index position** only takes effect when the table flat mode is enalbe.

so you can use this code:

```
$collection->addAttributeToSort('position'); // Default SORT_ORDER_ASC
```