# Magento 2 product collection category filter category position sort

Tags: magento2, category, category-products, sort-by-position

Hi i am trying to get product collection with category filter and category position sorting but it not working
i tried below way

```
 $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addCategoriesFilter(array('eq' => $category->getId()));//
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('position'); 
//->setOrder('cat_index_position','ASC')
```

please any one tell me how to sort category positon

Comment: You're trying to get the products from a category and order them with "Position", the attribute position references the products or the category?

Comment: category position     https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/286742/magento-2-x-sort-product-collection-by-category-product-position

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

`$collection->getSelect()->order('cat_index_position', 'ASC');`